# How to identify dynamically generated image id's in a table row by using nightwatch JS

Tags: xpath, nightwatch.js

I have a table in that each row have some information. In one of the rows, images are available and also they are clickable. I need to click one of the image which has dynamic id.

Please refer below source code

```
<tr id="tblRow_2">
<td height="25" colspan="8" style="border: none; text-align: right">
<input id="PPPayNow_0" type="image"  src="/Client/images/paynowprepay.gif" onclick="pppayClick(0,35);"/>
<input id="PayNow_0" type="image" src="/Client/images/paynow.gif"  onclick="payClick(0,35);" alt=""/>
</td> 
<td></td>
<td id="paymentTotal_0" style="text-align:right; font-size:medium; font-weight:bold; color:Black; border:none"></td>
```

I have tried  CSS selectors & x-path but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using X-Path preceding siblings and x-path string functions for preceding Axes i.e. number string-length(string?) it returns the number of characters in the string . number string-length(string?) => this function I used for identifying input tag which will be enable after clicking checkbox.

solution is :
browser.useXpath().click('//*[@id="tableId"]/tbody/tr/td[3][string-length(text()) > 0]/preceding::td[2]/input[starts-with(@id, "PayNow")]');

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the onclick attribute values are constantly- they are js functions after all,  so should be, this is how you can select the 1st input:

```
//td/input[starts-with(@onclick, "pppayClick")]
```

And this is for the 2nd:

```
//td/input[starts-with(@onclick, "payClick")]
```

You could do the same with the id attribute, if only the prefixes (the `_0` part) change.